# Scroll to an element with Appium, wd and React Native

Tags: android, react-native, webdriver, appium

I'm trying to scroll down to a button in my react native integration tests. I'm using appium version 1.21.0, UiAutomator2 and [wd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wd) to run the tests on Android emulator, but cannot find a way to scroll in my tests. Is there a way to implement scroll with JS, wd and appium?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some of the code we use to do scrolling. The technique differs between iOS and Android:

```
const element = driver.waitForElementById(...);

if (platformIsIOS()) {
  await driver.execute("mobile: scroll", {
    element,
    direction: distY <= 0 ? "down" : "up",
  });

} else {
  let action = new wd.TouchAction(driver);
  action.press({ el: element, x: fromX, y: fromY });
  action.wait(Timeouts.Default);
  action.moveTo({ el: elementName, x: fromX + distX, y: fromY + distY });
  action.release();
  for (let i = 0; i < repeatTimes; i++) {
    await action.perform();
  }
}
```